# Reduce UIImage size is not working

Tags: ios, iphone

i am trying to reduce my image size to be less then 64000 bytes this is my code and logs.

```
    NSData *beforeData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo, 1.0);
    NSLog(@"Size of Image(MB):%u",[beforeData length]/1048576);

    float compression = 0.6;
    NSData* imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo, compression);
    while ([imgData length] > 400) {
       compression -= 0.1;
        imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo, compression);
     }

   UIImage *result = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
  NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(result, 1.0);
  NSLog(@"Size of Image(MB):%u",[data length]/1048576);
```

**LOG**:

- Size of Image(MB):2
- Size of Image(MB):2

i do not know why the size stay the same .. maybe i need to use

```
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just changing the JPEG compression in your loop the file size will descrease.
But when you create a `UIImage` from the JPG data the the size, of the `UIImage` is not depened on the size of the JPG data.

The size of an `UIImage` is base on  the height x width x 4 in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing is the size of a compressed image another is the size of an image opened into memory and then saved again.
I will try to make an example: say that you are leaving for holiday and you need to put a lot of stuff in a bag, they will not fit inside it, you must compress them.
To do that you sit on the top of the bag and you close it. 
Later you open it again and trying to close without compressing again.
That's what you are doing.
If you want to reduce the size of the image you should reduce his pixels area, if you want to keep the pixel dimensions, you can save the compression value inside an local variable.

An image open will occupy something like : `H` x `W` x `number of channel` x `number of bit for channel`. That means that an image with 4 channels RGBA 8 bit (1 byte each) will occupy: H x W x 4
bytes

Answer (score 0):

You're logging the size of an image with a 1.0 compression ratio. Why don't you log `[imgData length]` instead of `[data length]` in the last line?

```
    NSData *beforeData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo, 1.0);
    NSLog(@"Size of Image(MB):%u",[beforeData length]/1048576);

    float compression = 0.6;
    NSData* imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo, compression);
    while ([imgData length] > 400) {
       compression -= 0.1;
        imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo, compression);
     }

   UIImage *result = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
   NSLog(@"Size of Image after (MB):%u",[imgData length]/1048576);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new image from the compressed data. If the compression did reduce the data length you would end up with an infinite loop. Simply change the three lines to:

```
NSLog(@"Size of Image(MB):%u",[imgData length]/1048576);
```

Answer (score 0):

When i am trying to print

```
NSLog(@"Size of Image(MB):%u",[imgData length]/1048576);
```

it is look like it's ok, but when i am create the image again from the NSData i have just created, the size return to be 2MB.